# How can one Client can subscribe to two groups in Multicasting

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I am new to this field of programming. I want to set up a system where there will be one client who is subscribed to the two multicast groups. I am using the below code to do this for one client subscribed to one group. Can any one help me how to add this client to another group for `setsockopt` like this?

```
group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.9");

if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
{
  perror("Adding multicast group error");
  close(sd);
  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the option is called `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP.` Just repeat what you already have for another group. A socket can join several groups. The limit is rather low but it is greater than one,